# performance issue in c++ code with numeric computation

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, time-complexity

I want to Optimize a C/C++ code. after analyzing all aspects of code I found that the function bellow takes about 99% of the execution time.

```
for (l = i+1; l < m->_n ; ++l)       /* m->_n is about 650      this loop takes about 100 ms   */
{
    m = add_line(m, l, i);

    deg[l] = (deg[i] > deg[l]) ? deg[i] : deg[l];
}

/* add_line function */
MAT* add_line (MAT* mat, int dst, int src)
{
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < mat->_m; ++j)           // mat->_m is about 650
        mat->_v[dst][j] = (mat->_v[dst][j] + mat->_v[src][j]) & 1;

    return mat;
}

/* also MAT is a struct. _n & _m are width and height of the matrix. */
typedef struct                                      
{
    int _n, _m, **_v;
} MAT;
```

I wonder if I use 2D c++ std::vector rather than MAT struct maybe speed grows faster?
Is there any other solution to optimize this code?

I think 100 ms for this nested loops is very huge and maybe a bad mistake causes this.
regard.

Comment: You may like to post your complete benchmarking code with its inputs, it helps your readers help you.

Comment: FYI, there is no language "C/C++".  You're either programming in C or C++.  They are distinct languages.

Comment: You may want to put your `for` loop limit into a constant local variable.  This may be performed by the compiler, depending on the optimization level.

Comment: BTW, in C++, you don't need `typedef` before the `struct`.  Structure tags are the names of the type.

Comment: i am wondering if i use std::vector instead of struct. mybe performance gets better?

Comment: You may be able to chop off some time by making `mat->_v[dst]` and `mat->v[src]` into temporary pointers.Without optimizations, this modification and reduce two indirections per expression.

Comment: If the complete matrix only contains 0s and 1s you could vectorize the whole problem and represent multiple adjacent cells by a single `long`-value. Line addition would then consist of simply xoring those values. Should speed the whole thing up by quite a bit. Also try using a one-dimensional array instead of a two-dimensional one to reduce memory reads a bit.

Comment: Please show how you compiled that program, how you benchmarked it, and a complete [repro]. That loop should not take 100ms with the number of values that you mentioned.

Comment: @Paul thanks you and others. i think my values are 0, 1. maybe xoring will imporve the code.

Comment: The std::vector will give in your case no performance boost. Please post more details of your code and make it compiler runable. This will help with your case.

Comment: Why do you return `mat` from you `add_line` and re-assigning it to `m`? This may prevent some compiler optimizations. Also, `deg[l] = (deg[i] > deg[l]) ? deg[i] : deg[l];` is simply `if(deg[i] > deg[l]) deg[l] = deg[i];`